# Hiding a Prism region when using View based Navigation

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <UserControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.ShellHeaderRegion}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
    <UserControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.ShellStatusRegion}" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" />
    <UserControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.ShellContentRegion}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Greetings,

I am building a WPF Prism app with multiple modules. Some modules utilize all 3 regions I defined. (Header, Content, Status). Other modules only utilize the content region. The problem is when I navigate from one module to another using `IRegionManager.RequestNavigate()`, the ShellHeaderRegion and ShellContentRegion still contain the injected views. I would like the ability to deactivate these views, while keeping the ability to reactivate these views when I call `IRegionNavigationJournal.GoBack()`. Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running a few tests and reading the source code I was able to find a suitable solution.
If you want to hide a Region you will need to create an empty UserControl. Since it has no content it will have no width/height and collapse.

Unfortunately, the only way to call `IRegionNavigationJournal.GoBack()` would be from the `IRegion`, since implementing `INavigationAware` on the empty UserControl doesn't really help (Unless you add UI elements or events that can call `IRegionNavigationJournal.GoBack()`)

[image]